# Thymeleaf view doesn't pass entity ID to a Spring @Controller, but does it with other properties

Tags: java, spring, model, thymeleaf

When I go to `/add` endpoint my Controller creates a `Contact` object and generates an ID for it. This ID is then properly passed to a Thymeleaf view and showed on the webpage. When the form from the view is submitted (with POST) to another endpoint in my Controller all of the properties are passed except the ID field. I use Spring Model and `@ModelAttribute` annotation to pass the object to and from the view. Getters and setters for the entity are generated with Lombok.

Controller class:

```
@Controller
public class PhonebookController {

    private final PhonebookService phonebookService;

    @Autowired
    public PhonebookController(PhonebookService phonebookService) {
        this.phonebookService = phonebookService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/add")
    public String addContact(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("contact", new Contact(EntityUtils.generateId()));
        return "contact";
    }

    @PostMapping("/save")
    public String validateAndSaveContact(@ModelAttribute("contact") @Valid Contact contact, BindingResult bindingResult) { // contact.getId() returns null
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "contact";
        }
        phonebookService.getContactRepository().save(contact);
        return "redirect:/contacts";
    }
}
```

Entity class:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Document(indexName = "contact")
public class Contact implements Comparable<Contact> {

    @Id
    private String id;
    @NotEmpty(message = "Name can not be empty.")
    private String name;
    @NotEmpty(message = "Number can not be empty.")
    @Pattern(regexp = "[0-9]+", message = "Number can contains only numbers.")
    private String number;

    public Contact(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Contact o) {
        return this.getName().compareTo(o.name);
    }
}
```

Thymeleaf view:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/webjars/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/webjars/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/webjars/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <h1>Add new contact</h1>
                <form th:action="@{/save}" method="post" th:object="${contact}">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="idText">Identifier (automaticaly generated):</label>
                        <strong id="idText" th:text="${contact.getId()}"></strong>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="nameInput">Contact name:</label>
                        <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" th:value="*{name}" class="form-control" id="nameInput"/>
                        <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors()}" th:errors="*{name}"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="numberInput">Phone number:</label>
                        <input type="text" th:field="*{number}" th:value="*{number}" class="form-control" id="numberInput"/>
                        <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors()}" th:errors="*{number}"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group text-right">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Confirm</button>
                        <a class="btn btn-danger" th:href="@{/contacts}" role="button">Cancel</a>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a hidden input field which contains the id value.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="idText">Identifier (automaticaly generated):</label>
    <strong id="idText" th:text="${contact.getId()}"></strong>
    <input id="id" th:field="*{id}" type="hidden"/> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to help you, but I don´t know if you are using the same object to save the data in your table (your entity) and for return your view model in your controller. Normally you should use a different objects and mapping this in your service. It is posible that you have problems if you are using the same object.